# How can I delete image uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My html code is like this :

```
<input type='file' multiple/>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {
?>
    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>">
        <button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
            for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
            }        
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
        var IsImgAdded=false;
        $('.img-container').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
                $(this).append(imgTmpl);
                IsImgAdded=true;
                $(this).find('.show-button').show();
            }
        });     
    };

    $(".show-button").click(function(){
        $(this).find('img').hide()
    });
```

Demo and full code is like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu9x-w50q

I try use hide the image. But it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: $(".show-button").on("click", function() {
$(this).siblings('img').hide();
});

Comment: @Gerard, It works. But, it just remove the image. How to remove "delete icon" also?

Comment: Add this inside the function: $(this).hide();

Comment: @Gerard, It worked, but it was a bit strange. When I uploaded 3 images. Then I deleted 2 images. Then I uploaded 1 images. Image uploaded to box number 4. should be to box number 2 first. Look at this : https://postimg.org/image/dw0rlysl5/

Comment: To be specific, there is no uploading operation in your code, meaning that you can't delete an image u haven't uploaded. Maybe you're talking about removing an image tag from the document lineup so that you can get rid of the image that has/had been added to the document flow. please be specific and also i checked your code and couldn't find any PHP/Serverside uploading code.

Comment: That's because the image/button is not deleted, but hidden as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `parent` method in order to achieve this, because `image` DOM element belongs to the `parent` of `.show-button`.

```
$(document).on('click',".show-button",function(){
    var imgTmpl = '<div class="img-container">'+
               '<button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-button">'+
               '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'+
                '</button></div>';
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('body').append(imgTmpl);
});
```

Here is [solution.](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/edsm-myp3)

Comment: It works. But, it just remove the image. How to remove "delete icon" also?

Comment: It worked, but it was a bit strange. When I uploaded 3 images. Then I deleted 2 images. Then I uploaded 1 images. Image uploaded to box number 4. should be to box number 2 first. Look at this : https://postimg.org/image/dw0rlysl5/

Comment: @samueltoh, you should use `remove` method instead.Have a look to updated answer.

Comment: You should also have $(this).remove(); or $(this).show(); somewhere

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, It works. But there is still 1 deficiency again. For example I uploaded 3 images. Then I delete the image in the first box. I want the image on box 2 to shift to the first box. While the image on the third box shifts to the second box. How to do it?

Comment: @Gerard, Okay. There still is a shortfall again

Comment: @samueltoh, that cannot be achieve with the your current code.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Why? Do I have to change all my code?

Comment: @samueltoh, i think i develop a solution. Have a look to my answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Great. It works. But when I implement to my actual code. It's not perfect yet. When I uploaded 5 images. Then I delete 1 image. Plus icon does not appear again. My actual code : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9kb1-r47h

Comment: @samueltoh, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, I'm sorry. I think you will update your code according to my actual code

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Are you able to help me with my case http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9kb1-r47h ? I have trouble doing it. Do I need to create a new question?

Comment: @samueltoh, create a new question.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Okay. I will create a new question

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111709/how-do-i-show-back-the-plus-button-when-delete-image

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, Seems, I need you help again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176608/how-to-remove-the-uploaded-image-in-any-box/44180074#44180074. My case is similar to before. But this one I use singe input type file and show hidden to remove and add the image

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Miha, Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674975/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz1aKLkf_TAhWHrI8KHUVvCXkQFgi9ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ&sig2=hab84BeZwFeMPR53Pv8j8A)

```
 $(".show-button").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.img-container').find('img').hide()
        //$(this).closest('.img-container').children().remove() used for remove the all child element of the `.img-container`
        console.log('hi')
    });
```

Comment: It works. But, it just remove the image. How to remove "delete icon" also?

Comment: *`//$(this).closest('.img-container').children().remove() used for remove the all child element of the .img-container`* see this .I was comment on this snippet .you could enable it.It remove all the innerchild