# How do I show back the plus button when delete image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My html code is like this :

```
<input type='file' multiple style="display: none;" id="upload-file" />
<?php   
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) { ?>

    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>" data-status="0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product"<?php 
            if($i!=0) echo' style="display:none;"'; ?> >
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>

        <button  style="display: none;" class="btn btn-danger show-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
...
$(document).on('click',".show-button",function(){
    var imgTmpl = '<div class="img-container">'+
               '<button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-button">'+
               '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'+
                '</button></div>';
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('body').append(imgTmpl);
});
```

Demo and full code is like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9kb1-r47h

My problem is : when I uploaded 5 images. Then I delete 1 image. Plus icon does not appear again.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: your appending wrong button you need to append this one <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </button>

Comment: You should append the full div with `plus` icon.

Comment: It's better if you answer this question with the code. So if your answer is correct, I can accept your answer

Comment: what about just replacing the delete img by the icon `+` at the time you do it ? `$(this).parent().remove().append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like this , it is work for me,

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .img-container {
        width: 162px;
        height: 142px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .delete-button {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }

    .upload-add-product {
        margin-top: 55px;
        margin-left: 55px;
    }

    .img-container .show-button { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type='file' multiple style="display: none;" id="upload-file" />
<div class="images-area">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) { ?>

    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>" data-status="0" data-index="<?=$i?>">
        <?php if ($i == 0): ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click','.upload-add-product',function(){
        $("#upload-file").click();
    });

    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
            for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        var imgTmpl = '';
        var IsImgAdded=false;
        $('.img-container').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
                $(this).append(imgTmpl);
                IsImgAdded=true;

                $(this).attr('data-status',1);
                //$(this).find('.upload-add-product').hide();
                //$(this).find('.show-button').show();
                var i = $(this).closest('.img-container').data('index');
                var imgTmpl ='<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>'+
                           '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-button">'+
                           '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'+
                            '</button>';
                $('#box'+i).html('');
                $('#box'+i).append(imgTmpl);
                if(i<5) {
                    $('#box'+(i+1)).html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product">'+
                               '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'+
                                '</button>');
                }
                $('.img-container').each(function(){
                    if( $(this).attr('data-status') != 1){
                        $(this).find('.upload-add-product').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    };


    $(document).on('click','.delete-button',function(){
        var i = $(this).closest('.img-container').attr('data-index');
        $('#box'+i).remove();
        $('.images-area').append('<div class="img-container" data-status="0"></div>');
        var blank = 0;
        $('.img-container').each(function(i){
            $(this).attr({'id':'box'+i,'data-index':i});
            if(($(this).attr('data-status') == 0) && (blank == 0)) {
                console.log("k");
                blank = i;
            }
        });
        if($('.img-container').find('.upload-add-product').length == 0) {
            $('#box'+blank).append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product">'+
                       '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'+
                        '</button>');
        }
    });


</script>
```

Demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/w19L0bv8/)

May be it helps you...

Comment: There are still many shortcomings. Try uploading 5 image. Then you delete everything. The result is like this: https://postimg.org/image/d8xrvph4n/. There should be only 1 button add.

Comment: If you have free time. Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176608/how-to-remove-the-uploaded-image-in-any-box

Comment: sure.. why not!!!...I will help you .. but after some time...@samueltoh

Comment: No problem. You can help me if you have free time

Comment: hi @samueltoh.. see your solution here http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/f1gh-zpwq    .Sorry i can't understand your code but i tried by myself...

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot.Seems it works.No problem.I will understand your code and apply it to my case.Btw,I want to ask. What about name input file type. It will be used to save the image. I try like this : `<input type='file' style="display: none;" id="upload-file<?=$i?>" class="upload-file" name="photo-<?php echo $i; ?>"/>`.When I uploaded 3 pictures. And I delete the first image.Then I submit. Array results like this : https://postimg.org/image/723xgpebp/. How to order it like this: photo-0, photo-1, photo-2, photo-3?.So when the image was removed and saved.Its index name starts from 0

Comment: Check your question i put my code there with uploading..@samueltoh

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674975/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

You didn't even add the `+` button back in. I'd also suggest you look at template literals to help with formatting and multi-lined code.

You need to make sure that when you reach the end, that instead of having it set as `none` and waiting for something else to prompt it back to `block` or w/e, show it as `block` or w/e, intially

Updated parts:

```
$(document).on('click',".show-button",function(){
    let pos;
    let i = 0;
    let parent = $(this).parent()[0];

    $(".img-container").each( function() {
        if (this == parent)
        {
            pos = i;
        }
        i++;
    });

    let show = (pos === 4) ? "block" : "none";

    var imgTmpl = '<div class="img-container" data-status="0">'+
                    '<button style="display: ' + show +'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product" onclick="upload_click();">' +
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>' +
                '</button>' +
               '<button  style="display: none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-button">'+
               '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'+
                '</button></div>';
    //console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().remove();

    $('body').append(imgTmpl);
});     

function upload_click()
{
    $("#upload-file").click();
}
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xzq8-h3ub

Comment: You must login first to be able to save in phpfiddle,

Comment: It's still not perfect. If I uploaded 5 images. Then I delete the image on box other than box 5. for example box 1 or box 2 or box 3 or box 4, the button add disappear

Comment: works completely fine for me, (tested it). Maybe you're not replacing the parts correctly

Comment: added phpfiddle

Comment: I had try it again. But it does not work. I try your phpfiddle. You try upload 5 image. Then you delete image on the box 4. The add button disappear

Comment: not for me... I've tried it both filling all 5 and only partial filling. So you fill all 5 then delete 1 (any one or a particular one?) and it doesn't show the button at the very end?

Comment: What browser are you using also?

Comment: I try in chrome and firefox browser. But it does not work

Comment: is it only when you fill in all 5, is it when you fill in 4 things, delete 1, fill in another, then the last button does not show up?

Comment: Look at this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzDSCw8-sQI&feature=youtu.be. That is what I mean. Should when I delete the image, the add button still exists

Comment: very strange... because I just tested and it works... does your `$(document).on` look like what i've posted?

Comment: Yes. I try you phpfiddle and it looks like a video I uploaded on youtube

Comment: probably can't help you then, since I can't replicate the issue. It's definitely to do with the fact that you don't have the `plus` button in your original code, but after that, you'll need to attach listeners and what not. Try adding the `plus` button as visible initially and see if you can see it.

Comment: What do you mean with my original code. There is a plus button.   `button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product"<?php 
     if($i!=0) echo' style="display:none;"'; ?> >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </button>`

Comment: look at your original `$(document).on('click',".show-button",function()`. It only has the trash button. Line 81 onwards, where you save `imgTmpl`.

Comment: It solved. If you have free time. Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176608/how-to-remove-the-uploaded-image-in-any-box

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisite:**
Assign id to your delete button

Then On click of delete button, check if id =0 and accordingly apply style to your plus button as below.
Last step is to append newly created plus button to current div.

```
$(".btn-danger").click(function(){

$id=this.id;
if($id!=0){
var r= $('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product" style="display:none;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>');
}
else{
var r= $('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload-add-product">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>');
}


 $(this).parent().append($r);

});
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: It does not work. You should try that first before answering questions