# How to remove the uploaded image in any box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code is very long. I can not show you all here. I just show the javascript code only

My javascript like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let current = 0;
     for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-delete-'+i).click(function(){
            current -= 1;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').val('');
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+current).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+current).style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "";
        });
    }

    var editClicked = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-edit-'+i).click(function(){
            editClicked = true;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').click();
        });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-add-'+i).click(function(){
            editClicked = false;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').click();
        });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        var reader = new FileReader();     
        $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function (e) {
            let indexPhoto = i;
            current += 1;
            reader.onload = function(){
                imageProducIsLoaded(indexPhoto);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        });
    }

    function imageProducIsLoaded(indexPhoto) {
        $('#thumbnail-view-'+indexPhoto).attr('src', reader.result);
        if (!editClicked) {
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+indexPhoto).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+indexPhoto).style.display = "";
            if((indexPhoto+1) < 5) {
                document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(indexPhoto+1)).style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(indexPhoto+1)).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

You can see my complete code and demo here : http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/adjv-sfuy

I use show hide to add, delete and edit image. If you look at the demo, it has worked. Images can be edited, deleted and added

But my problem is when the user does delete image

When user delete an image, the image on last box is deleted. Should be when user delete an image, then the image that I click its delete button is deleted

For example I input 5 image. When deleting image to 3, image to 3 deleted

I've been trying to modify the code for some days, but I have not found a solution

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I don't get why you don't just have all the empty boxes display their `+` sign. That's simpler and doesn't really affect user experience.

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, try to stick to jquery rather than doing something like `document.getElementBy` just use `$("#blah")`. And you won't really get the effect of shifting stuff around with your current code as you're just showing/hiding divs.

Comment: @A. Lau, It is a great idea. But this is my client request. See jason's answer. It has reduced my problem. But there are still shortcomings.

Comment: Did you update your code with jason's recommendations?

Comment: @A. Lau, Not yet. I will update it

Comment: Your edit works fine. I can't see any problems

Comment: @A. Lau, I update my question and phpfiddle. The problem is : when I delete an image, the image on last box is deleted. Should be when I delete an image, then the image that I click its delete button is deleted

Comment: I have to say, your choice of HTML structuring is pretty poor for what you're trying to do. To get the shifting effect, I would simply just append the 'deleted' box to the end, and get the next one to show up. Kind of hard when you're just using a bunch of sequential `li`s

Comment: @A. Lau, So for my case, is it only able to follow answer from jason? Is there no other solution? When I work on this case. I think show hide is the easiest solution

Comment: I was thinking that you should shift the images instead. So still do your normal shifting, and just shift the `img src` as well as any other attributes along with it.

Comment: @A. Lau, It looks like it will change the whole of my code. I have to rewrite my code

Comment: I've shifted the `src` of the images, but you might have to fix some other places so the data is passed correctly or w/e. See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery features for doing complex things very simple.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES);$i++) {

        if($_FILES['photo-'.$i]['error'] == 0) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['photo-'.$i]['name'];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['photo-'.$i]['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"img/".$file_name);
        }
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
.img-container{width:162px;height:142px;border:1px dashed #337ab7;float:left;margin-right:5px;position:relative;border-radius:5px}
.upload-add-product{position:absolute;display:block;margin:34% 42%}
.upload-add-product i{font-size:30px}
.img-container ul{list-style:none;bottom:0;position:absolute;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7)}
.img-container ul li{display:inline;padding:0;display:table-cell;width:1%;text-align:center;position:relative;padding:2px 0}
.img-container ul li:hover{background-color:#eee}
.img-container ul li a{color:red}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="images-area">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>" data-status="0" data-index="<?=$i?>">
        <input type='file' name="photo-<?=$i?>" style="visibility: hidden;position:absolute;" id="upload-file<?=$i?>" class="upload-file"/>
        <div class="image">
            <?php if ($i == 0): ?>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn-click upload-add-product" onclick="$('#upload-file<?=$i?>').click()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change',".upload-file",function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        var inputFiles = this.files;
        if(inputFiles == undefined || inputFiles.length == 0) return;
        var inputFile = inputFiles[0];
        var i = parseInt($(this).closest('.img-container').attr('data-index'));
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            // console.log($('#box'+i).find('img').length);
            if($('#box'+i).find('img').length) {
                $('#box'+i).find('img').attr('src',event.target.result);
            } else {
                var imgTmpl ='<img height="142" width="162" src='+event.target.result+'>'+
                           '<ul><li class="btn-click"  onclick=\'$("#upload-file'+i+'").click()\'><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></li>'+
                           '<li class="delete-button"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></li></ul>';
                $('#box'+i+' .image').html('');
                $('#box'+i+' .image').append(imgTmpl);
                $('#box'+i).attr('data-status',1);

                $('#box'+(i+1)+' .image').html('<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-click upload-add-product" onclick=\'$("#upload-file'+(i+1)+'").click()\'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');

            }
        };
        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("I AM ERROR: " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
    });


    $(document).on('click','.delete-button',function(){
        var i = $(this).closest('.img-container').attr('data-index');
        $('#box'+i).remove();
        $('.images-area').append('<div class="img-container" data-status="0"><input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload-file" class="upload-file"><div class="image"></div></div>');
        var blank = 0;
        $('.img-container').each(function(i){
            $(this).attr({'id':'box'+i,'data-index':i});
            $(this).find('.upload-file').attr({'id':'upload-file'+i,'name':'photo-'+i});
            $(this).find('.btn-click').attr('onclick','$("#upload-file'+i+'").click()');
            if(($(this).attr('data-status') == 0) && (blank == 0)) {
                blank = i;
            }
        });
        if($('.img-container').find('.upload-add-product').length == 0) {
            $('#box'+blank+' .image').append('<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-click upload-add-product" onclick=\'$("#upload-file'+blank+'").click()\'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I put efforts for understand your task..

See this it will help you..

Comment: Great. Thanks. Looks like your way better. I will apply to my case

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was misunderstand.

Mayby you need a judgement after you delete an image that make sure the next image is not show.

```js
$('#thumbnail-view-delete-'+i).click(function(){
  $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').val('');
    document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+i).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+i).style.display = "";
    if(document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+(i+1)).style.display === "none"){
      document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(i+1)).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(i+1)).style.display = "";
    }
});
```

This can descrease the messy.

Comment: You should read my question well. And before answering it, you should try it first

Answer (score 0):

I have found out your problem. Your delete function does not detect the number of photos currently uploaded but simply deletes the last one.

Added: current photo count, changed delete method to use current instead of 'i', increment count on upload and decrement count on delete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let current = 0;
     for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-delete-'+i).click(function(){
            current -= 1;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').val('');
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+current).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+current).style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "";
        });
    }

    var editClicked = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-edit-'+i).click(function(){
            editClicked = true;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').click();
        });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        $('#thumbnail-view-add-'+i).click(function(){
            editClicked = false;
            $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').click();
        });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
        var reader = new FileReader();     
        $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function (e) {
            let indexPhoto = i;
            current += 1;
            reader.onload = function(){
                imageProducIsLoaded(indexPhoto);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        });
    }

    function imageProducIsLoaded(indexPhoto) {
        $('#thumbnail-view-'+indexPhoto).attr('src', reader.result);
        if (!editClicked) {
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+indexPhoto).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+indexPhoto).style.display = "";
            if((indexPhoto+1) < 5) {
                document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(indexPhoto+1)).style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(indexPhoto+1)).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. Eg I uploaded 5 images, then I delete the image in the third box. Then the image on the third box is removed

Comment: Actually your answer has reduced my problem. It's just that when I delete an image, the image on last box is deleted. Should be when I delete an image, then the image that I click its delete button is deleted

Comment: Yeah I see it didn't completely fixed it. I got close when I tried editing it again but I'd suggest a rewrite. The code's quite messy and theres too many states to track.

Comment: If I rewrite the code. Do you have another better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0h1g-mvus

I just shift the images instead. You might need to do some changes to pass values or w/e.

```
let current = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
    $('#thumbnail-view-delete-'+i).click(function(){
        current -= 1;
        $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').val('');
        document.getElementById("thumbnail-view-li-"+current).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+current).style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("thumbnail-slot-li-"+(current+1)).style.display = "";
        shift_image(i);
    });
}

function shift_image(start)
{
    let finish = 4;
    for (; start < finish - 1; start++)
    {
        let next = $('#thumbnail-view-'+(start+1)).attr('src');
        $('#thumbnail-view-'+start).attr('src', next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Seems not perfect yet. I try uploaded 5 pictures. Then I delete the first picture, I see the deleted picture is not the first picture, but the fifth picture. Should the deleted picture is the first picture

Comment: Your code : `for (; start < finish - 1; start++)`, 
it was a bit strange. I saw it for the first time. Loop usually like this : `for (i=0; i < test; i++)`

Comment: that's because those are optional, you can even have `for(;;)`. It just makes an infinite loop. I didn't need to define anything because I already had it defined.

Comment: Okay. Do you have another better idea? I've fixed the bug. But when using show hide, it seems like it takes a lot of work to make it perfect

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674975/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button